# Count the number of elements in a string separated by comma

Tags: python, text, text-mining

I am dealing with text strings such as the following:
`LN1 2DW, DN21 5BJ, DN21 5BL, ...`

In Python, how can I count the number of elements between commas? Each element can be made of 6, 7, or 8 characters, and in my example there are 3 elements shown. The separator is always a comma.

I have never done anything related to text mining so this would be a start for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can count the number of commas:

```
text.count(",") + 1
# 3
```

Comment: I'm curious to see a benchmark of this approach (str.count()) vs. split + len. If you have the time, feel free. :-)

Comment: Yes I'd also like to know what's more efficient - counting commas or splitting and using len?

Comment: @BramVanroy Done a real quick test using `ipython` and its `%timeit` built-in. Results:

`text.count(',')+1`: 665 ns ± 3.06 ns per loop

`len(text.split(','))`: 3.59 µs ± 19.3 ns per loop

Tested data was a list of 91 elements.

Comment: @KMunro see my earlier comment.

Answer (score 13):

If the comma (`,`) is the separator, you can simply use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the string and then [`len(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#len) on the result:

```
text = 'LN1 2DW, DN21 5BJ, DN21 5B'
number = len(text.split(','))
```

You can also reuse the list of elements. For instance:

```
text = 'LN1 2DW, DN21 5BJ, DN21 5B'
tags = text.split(',')
number = len(tags)
#do something with the `tags`
```

Comment: Text.count (',')+1

Comment: This work indeed more efficiently, but the next step is probably iterating over the elements.

Comment: Spaces are not ignored here

Comment: @sagar: in the loop, one can use `.strip` etc. to simply post-process every element.

Comment: I'm curious to see a benchmark of this approach (split + len) vs. str.count(). If you have the time, feel free. :-)

Comment: @BramVanroy: well `.split(..)` is definitely less efficient. It first of all will result in a linear amount of `malloc`s, and furthermore most Python interpreters use some flyweight patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Willien and Psidom already mentioned `count`,

I just wanted to add that in python a string is also iteratable, thus list comprehension could also be applied:

```
n = len([c for c in ','+text if c==','])
```

Or

```
n = sum(1 for c in ','+text if c==',')
```

Comment: Why would you do this? SO should provide the best answers not all possible alternatives

Comment: Feel free to vote down, if my answer is against SO policy I'm sure you could ask a moderator to delete it

Comment: You're not breaking any rules, but why present worse alternatives than existing answers. There are so many possible answers, like you could include `len(list(filter(lambda x: ord(x) == 44, text)))+1` too but it really doesn't add anything